# Running a system check after AppRegistry is initialized - Django Admin

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-admin

I'm looking to run a specific check, to make sure that Django Admin classes (ModelAdmin, TabularInline etcetera) used within the project (within multiple apps) are using or inheriting from a class (a mixin in this case) - *although a system check would fail since the `AppRegistry` is not yet loaded.*

I'm using the below as of current; although this raises that the `AppRegistry` is not loaded.

```
from django.contrib.admin.sites import all_sites
from django.core.checks import register, Error

@register()
def check_django_admin_inheritance(app_configs, **kwargs):
    errors = []

    for admin_site in all_sites:
        for model, admin in admin_site._registry.items():
            if MyMixin not in admin.__class__.__bases__:
                errors.append(
                    Error('All admin sites should derive from the MyMixin (common.django_admin)',
                          hint='Inherit from MyMixin or use our custom ModelAdmin (common.django_admin)',
                          obj=admin, id="id-here")
                )

    return errors
```

Is there any other way around this; besides the `AppConfig.ready()` which would require that I place it in every application - I'm more looking towards a solution that is clean and centralized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply register your check **inside** the `AppConfig.ready()` of some suitable app. Also you write `errors.append([Error(...)])` which means you append a list of errors to the list you are supposed to return which will give you an error:

```py
from django.contrib.admin.sites import all_sites
from django.core.checks import register, Error


def check_django_admin_inheritance(app_configs, **kwargs):
    errors = []

    for admin_site in all_sites:
        for model, admin in admin_site._registry.items():
            if MyMixin not in admin.__class__.__bases__:
                errors.append(
                    Error('All admin sites should derive from the MyMixin (common.django_admin)',
                          hint='Inherit from MyMixin or use our custom ModelAdmin (common.django_admin)',
                          obj=admin, id="id-here")
                )

    return errors


class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    ...
    
    def ready(self):
        register(check_django_admin_inheritance) # Register the check here
```

I write this in my own app, and the check gives an error message for `User` and `Group` of the `auth` app, so this works as intended.

Comment: Did you just put that in the `apps.py` and then in the `INSTALLED_APPS`? because I'm still getting the error: `django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.`

Comment: I've also removed the list surrounding the `Error` from the question - that was an issue with the example I added in the question.

Comment: Say you use the model in the `MyMixin`, that will cause an exception since the app registry is not ready (`AppRegistryNotReady`)

Comment: @JulianCamilleri you likely still have that original code of yours. Don't register the check anywhere else, just register it in the `ready` method of an app. If you still get the error it is likely from somewhere else (add your _complete_ traceback to the question).

Comment: I managed to find the issue - I didn't have the code there still - everything was fine, but was importing the model outside of the function - which would of course, be executed before the `AppRegistry` is loaded - seems to work, thank you!